# Implicit conversion in type declaration? What is object type that is stored on the heap?

Tags: .net, implicit-conversion, type-declaration

Ok imagine I have a base class `BaseClass`, as well as a child class `ChildClassA` which derives from `BaseClass`.

What happens when I do this?

`BaseClass b = new ChildClassA;`

What I imagine is happening is that:

1. ChildClassA gets created and stored on the heap *as a `ChildClassA` type*!
2. The variable `b` gets assigned a reference to the ChildClassA
3. There is an implicit conversion from the ChildClassA to BaseClass
4. But the object is still stored in the heap as a ChildClassA

The reason I ask is that as I understand it, once an object is declared and stored on the heap, that's what it ALWAYS is. A conversion just tells the CLR to *treat* it like it's a different type, but it really always still is the original type, and *knows* it's still the original type.

Am I correct? Anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're spot on with your understanding.

`b` refers to the `ChildClassA` instance.  The latter is still on the heap as it was previously and no new objects are heapificated as a result of the assignment of the instance to `BaseClass b`.

Answer (score 2):

By Jove, you've got it!

> A conversion just tells the CLR to
>   treat it like it's a different type,

Actually it's not a conversion, more like an interpretation.